# Connect multiple many-to-many relationships to each other

Tags: sql, database

I want to model a scheme in which there are some items, some user and some tags. So I have a database in which I have three tables: `User`, `Tag` and `Item`.

Each user can assign some tags to the item. Just looking at the relationship between `Item` and `Tag` I would say that this is a classical many-to-many relationship - each `Item` can have multiple `Tag` elements assigned. So far it is clear.

The problematic part now is that each user can use its own tags and they may or may not be the same that other users have used. In SQL I think this can be modeled with a unique slug for each `Tag` that is reused if it exists and will be created if not.

Now this seems like an additional many-to-many relationship. Each `Tag` can be assigned by multiple `User` elements (for multiple items). But how do I join both many-to-many relationships efficiently?

In the end I want to be able to say something like this:

- `Tag1`, `Tag2` are assigned to `Item1`
- `Tag1` is shared by `User1` and `User2` for `Item1` but not by `User3`
- `Item1` is tagged by `Tag1` by `N` users

How can I translate this idea into a SQL scheme?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase it in order to see if I understood what you're saying.

1. There's a many-to-many relationship between item and tag. This means, every item can have multiple tags. Every tag can be a tag of multiple items.
2. Tags are assigned to items by users. This is also a many-to-many as any user can assign multiple tags and any tag can be assigned by multiple users.

Thus, in short, the tag to item assignment is done by some user and can be seen as a "private" action.

Assuming the following:

1. Users are identified by uid
2. Tags are identified by tid
3. Items are identified by iid.

Then the action of assigning a tag to an item by some user is described by the tuple (tid, iid, uid). This also describes the table, I'll call it T, you'll need.

Now to the questions you'd like to have answered (changed the order putting the most complex question at the end):

a. Tag1, Tag2 are assigned to item1

`select distinct tid

      from T

     where iid = 'Item1';`

b. Item1 is tagged with Tag1 by N users

`select count(*)   from T  where iid = 'Item1'    and tid = 'Tag1';`

c. Tag1 is shared by User1 and User2 for Item1 but not by User3    I'll have to rephrase this question, because it is unclear how to put the answer into a (relational) table, assuming you have an arbitrarily amount of tags, users, items.    So I'll assume that the information that Tag1 for Item1 is not shared by User3 is sufficient as an answer (to get the complementary set is an easy exercise).

`select uid

       from users

      where uid not in (
            select uid
              from T
             where tid = 'Tag1'
               and iid = 'Item1'
      );`

And before people start complaining this type of select statement is old fashioned and not-the-way-to-do-it. It provides the answer required and is sufficient for a POC. I'm not writing hyper-modern production proof code here, I'm designing a data model.

Comment: Yep, I think that does the trick. I somehow missed the possibility to create a intermediate table using three foreign fields. I have to look a bit deeper into the complementary set you mentioned, but I think this will be a sufficient starting point to find a good solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: `select uid from T where tid = 'Tag1' and iid = 'Item1'`, that simple :-)